# IPC with simple switch between named pipes and sockets

Tags: c++, boost, ipc, boost-asio, named-pipes

I search for some C++ ipc lib that allow me to simple switch between named pipes (local use) and tcp ip sockets so i can send messages outside computer.

My app have to parts. First is users space app second is service. I need to send short messages between them.

Platform Windows

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend

> Using RPC for IPC
>
> RPC enables applications to call
>   functions remotely. Therefore, RPC
>   makes IPC as easy as calling a
>   function. RPC operates between
>   processes on a single computer or on
>   different computers on a network.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365574(v=vs.85).aspx

and Best RPC Programming Practices :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373563(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Does rpc use tcpip protocol only? I was thinking to make named pipes because i dont want a troubles with firewalls on desktop machines.

Answer (score 1):

What platform are you targeting? While not with named pipes, but memory-mapped files, our [MsgConnect](http://www.eldos.com/msgconnect/) seems to fit your needs. It was designed specifically for tasks like yours. MsgConnect lets you send messages with data payload on the local system (using memory-mapped files or TCP or UDP sockets) or across network (using TCP or UDP sockets).

Comment: @userbb On Windows MMF would be more efficient than named pipes.

Comment: Do you have any numbers to validate that claim?

Comment: @Omer Numbers are local to usage scenario etc. . I know the internal architecture on kernel level, and it tells me that speed will be faster with carefully crafted MMF rather than with pipes.

Answer (score 1):

With [RCF C++](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/Rcf_Ipc_For_Cpp.aspx) you can switch your transport layer (be it named pipes, tcp and udp with Boost:ASIO, etc) quite seamlessly.